# Issues with displaying 2 pdfs on side by side containers users using ngx-extended-pdf-container

Tags: angular, pdf

I am trying to display two pdfs side by side as it is the user requirement to be able to compare two documents. The first container would load the pdf which I have assigned as it's source but then the second pdf would replace it on the same container instead of loading on the second container which it is assigned as the source for. Any help or insight on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf viewer you mentioned to my knowledge is not able to show 2 pdfs on the same site.

You can either:

- Show one pdf in the designated viewer and one in an iframe
- show both in an iframe. However every browser has a different built in pdf viewer, so the viewer won't be consistent across browsers.

Comment: ng2-pdf-viewer seem to work okay with displaying two pdfs but it does not seem to like blob sources. I can look into iframe. Thank you